# Cadastro de texto com emoticons

Tags: php, mysql

Tenho uma página onde um textarea permite que o usuário cole notícias. o conteúdo ali inserido é salvo em um banco de dados MYSQL para futuramente ser exibido na página do site.
Preciso que, se o usuário colar nesse textarea um texto que contenha algum emoticon, esse emoticon possa também ser salvo no banco de dados e exibido posteriormente. 
Alguém tem alguma solução pra me ajudar?

Comment: O que irá representar o emoticon será uma palavra reservada? ex.: [sorriso] [joinha] ... porque se sim, você pode tratar estas palavras reservadas na hora de mostrar a imagem na leitura da notícia

Comment: Não, exatamente por isso... podem ser diferentes "símbolos" que o usuário inserir

Comment: O que você já tentou, e o que deu de errado?

Answer (score 1):

Para isso tens de guardar a tua BD como `utf8mb4`

no MySQL:

```
SET NAMES utf8mb4;
ALTER DATABASE database_name CHARACTER SET = utf8mb4 
COLLATE = utf8mb4_unicode_ci;


ALTER TABLE table_name CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 
COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;


ALTER TABLE table_name CHANGE column_name column_name VARCHAR(140)      
CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL;
```

Depois é só fazeres normalmente como se fosse texto corrido.

Podes ler mais sobre isto aqui:http://andy-carter.com/blog/saving-emoticons-unicode-from-twitter-to-a-mysql-database

Answer (score 1):

Usando `preg_replace` você pode mapear os emoticons e substituir pela sua imagem correspondente. Inserindo a imagem diretamente ou formatando um elemento usando `css`.

---

Note que o exemplo irá retornar `<img "smiles/:].gif">`.

<sub>**exemplo:**</sub>

```
$string  = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur... :) :]';
$pattern = ['~(\:\))~' , '~(\:\])~'];
$replace = '<img "smiles/${1}.gif">';

echo preg_replace($pattern, $replace, $string);
```

<sub>**output:**</sub>

```
 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur.... <img "smiles/:).gif"> <img "smiles/:].gif">
```

---

Usando `css`, basta usar as classes `smiles_01` e `smiles_02` com o tamanho da imagem e o background.

<sub>**exemplo:**</sub>

```
$string  = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur... :) :]';
$pattern = ['~(\:\))~' , '~(\:\])~'];
$replace = ['<div class="smiles_01"></div>' , '<div class="smiles_02"></div>'];

echo preg_replace($pattern, $replace, $string);
```

<sub>**output:**</sub>

```
 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur... <div class="smiles_01"></div> <div class="smiles_02"></div>
```

Comment: Consegui salvar direto no banco de dados, alterando toda a codificação da base dados, tabelas e colunas para utf8mb4.

Answer (score -1):

Você pode salvar mais ou menos assim:

```
Um texto qualquer com um <img src="smile/1.png"/> qualquer
```

Ai na hora de salvar exibir no HTML já vai ser uma carinha qualquer. Entendeu?

Answer (score -4):

Uma outra alternativa sem precisar trocar a configuração da base:

1º criando uma função que verifica se existe emojis no texto

2º convertendo todas estas ocorrências para um novo padrão, por exemplo tudo que for emoji pode ser mais ou menos "[e-1f600], [e-1f610], etc. Fazendo assim, o que será salvo na base será apenas o texto.

3º quando precisar imprimir os emojis na tela, crie uma segunda função que verifica esse padrão [e-xxxx] e troca pelo unicode do emoji.